# How to scrape a specific html line that follow another html line

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape some data from a html-page that looks something like this

```html
<tr>
 <td> Some information <td>
 <td> 123 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> some other information </td>
 <td> 456 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> and the info continues </td>
 <td> 789 </td>
</tr>
```

What I want, is to obtain the html line that comes after a given html line. That is, if I see 'some other information' I want the output '456'. I thought of combining regex with .find_next from BeautifulSoup, but I haven't had any luck with this (I'm also not that familiar with regex). Anyone have a clue how to do it? In advance, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually with a mix of `regex` and `find_next` in BeautifulSoup you can achieve what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<tr>
 <td> Some information <td>
 <td> 123 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> some other information </td>
 <td> 456 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> and the info continues </td>
 <td> 789 </td>
</tr>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
x = soup.find('td', text = re.compile('some other information'))
print(x.find_next('td').text)
```

**Output**

> ' 456 '

**EDIT** replaced `x.find_next('td').contents[0]` by `x.find_next('td').text`, shorter